# Should Akka messages be unique for a sender-receiver pair?

Tags: scala, akka, unique, message

Best practices question:

Should an Akka message type (case class) be always only sent by a single type of actor and received only by a single type of actor?

*Example:*

Three actor types: `MainSender`, `MainReceiver`, `Worker`
`MainSender` sends a message `DoSomething(work)` to `MainReceiver`.
`MainReceiver` forwards the `DoSomething(work)` message to `Worker`.

Is this the best practice? Or would it be better to define a new case class for the other sender-receiver pair?

`MainSender` sends a message `DoSomething(work)` to `MainReceiver`.
`MainReceiver` sends a message `StartWorking(work)` to `Worker`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally send the same message to any actor as long as it makes sense in your architecture. It is totally encouraged to reuse your code.

As you suggested, that is exactly what the `forward` function does.

The same logic goes for `Exception`: if you want to throw an `Exception`, you can use an existing one if it fits your needs or create a new one otherwise.

Comment: Of course I know I _can_ forward it, I just wanted to know if I _should_ forward it (if advantages outweigh the disadvantages in other people's opinion). Thank you.